# Find text in document

Tags: vba, button, ms-word, find

I created VBA code in MS Word to search for a selected word among all the titles in my document that have the same formatting.

I'm working on a document with more than 500 titles. I need to find text under each of these titles. (The document lists the names of the local counties in each district, the titles being the name of each district.)

I write the name of the county I want to search, select that name with the mouse, and run the macro using the shortcut I put in the Quick Access menu.

I want to share this document with my colleagues. To work on their computers, I would have to install a similar shortcut on each one, which is not practical.

I created a MacroButton to run this macro. The problem is that, after selecting the text I want to search, when I double click the MacroButton, the selection disappears, resulting in a search for an empty value.

How can I create a VBA macro I can associate with a macro button, so it will work on every computer that opens this document?

The ideal scenario is the macro would search for the text inserted on a given line of the document (I suggest the first line, where users would insert the name they want to search) without the need of selecting the text to be searched.

```vb
Sub PROC()
'
' PROC Macro
'
'
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Size = 18
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = Selection.Text
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

Something like:

Print screen of MacroButton
[image]

Comment: Does your document not use styles for the headings/titles? That would  make find more efficient. You can use an [input box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) to get the text to search for.

Comment: Thanks. The text is not using headings and titles, but it's possible to transform all the text with the same format into headings/titles. I'll try that approach

Comment: If you are using Word extensively without a thorough understanding of styles, you are shooting yourself in the foot. Trying to write vba without that understanding is an exercise designed to bring on frustration. Take a look at https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview and https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating Word documents you should always use styles, especially for headings/titles - for 16 reasons why see https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/usebuiltinheadingstyles.html

This will help your colleagues as they will then be able to use the Navigation pane to view the headings in the document as well as using your macro.

As an example for your macro using Heading 1 style:

```
Sub PROC()
    Dim textToFind As String
    textToFind = InputBox(Prompt:="Type name of district you want to find", Title:="Find district")
    With ActiveDocument.Content
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = textToFind
            .Style = wdStyleHeading1
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        If .Find.Execute Then .Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This really solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your time and patient. I'm sure you all noticed I'm a rookie in this area...

Answer (score 0):

By it's nature, clicking on a MacroButton field selects the field any action you take to add text will replace it. You cannot select text in the document and then click on a macrobutton field in the document. You lose the selection.

Start using instead a QAT button, perhaps that calls up a UserForm.

Or, perhaps, a Content Control with an on exit macro that does things with the content. The macro you are activating should be in the document with the button or its attached template for it to be portable. A macrobutton field in the document does not carry a macro stored elsewhere with it.

### You can put a QAT (Quick Access Toolbar) button in your document or template

The place to do this is in the Modify the Quick Access Toolbar dialog. (The Customize the Ribbon dialog has no such option.)

[image: screenshot of Modify the QAT dialog]

You are allowed only two spots, the default which is a separate file on your computer and the currently active document. The template attached to the active document is *not* an option, you would need the template itself to be open for editing.

**It is important that if the button is to a macro, that the macro be stored in the same document or template that you are using for the QAT modification.** You can also store *Keyboard shortcuts* to your macro and can include those in the label. This is often done with the built-in shortcuts.

[image: screenshot buttons with keyboard shortcuts]

Here is [my article on assigning keyboard shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330). As with macros, any such keyboard shortcut should be stored in the same file as the macro it is calling.

I have added buttons to a number of global templates and they work fine. When the template is loaded as an Add-In, the QAT modification appears.

Here is [my page on Modifying the QAT in Microsoft Word](https://addbalance.com/word/QATmodification.htm#PageStart).

It is possible, using XML modification, to add more extended tooltips than the label to such a button. That is discussed on my page. Here are some examples:

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]  [image: screenshot]

You can find examples of templates with QAT modifications (and Ribbon modifications) in [my Downloads page](https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#AddIns).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Guess I explained poorly my problem. The macro command I added to QTA works fine, what I need is to put a button inside the document that would work for every user that opens it. 

I created a button using the code {MacroButton PROC Search text above}. It does not work because when I double click it, the text selection is removed and the search comes back empy.

Comment: I've just added a print screen of the button I've created to the main question. Thanks

Comment: By it's nature, clicking on a MacroButton field selects the field any action you take to add text will replace it. You cannot select text in the document and then click on a macrobutton field in the document. You lose the selection. Start using instead a QAT button, perhaps that calls up a UserForm. Or, perhaps, a Content Control with an on exit macro that does things with the content.